# Remove elements from a c++ vector where the removal condition is dependent on other elements

Tags: c++, stl

The standard way to remove certain elements from a vector in C++ is the remove/erase idiom. However, the predicate passed to `remove_if` only takes the vector element under consideration as an argument. Is there a good STL way to do this if the predicate is conditional on other elements of the array?

To give a concrete example, consider removing all duplicates of a number immediately following it. Here the condition for removing the n-th element is conditional on the (n-1)-th element.

Before: 11234555111333
After: 1234513

Comment: Your example is an example of the **unique** algorithm in STL. Do check out the whole list of STL algorithms, you may find your needed answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's a standard algorithm for this. `std::unique` will remove the elements that are duplicates of those preceding them (actually, just like `remove_if` it reorganizes the container so that the elements to be removed are gathered at the end of it).

Example on a `std::string` for simplicity:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "11234555111333";
    str.erase(std::unique(str.begin(), str.end()), str.end());
    std::cout << str;   // 1234513
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others mentioned `std::unique` already, for your specific example. Boost.Range has the [`adjacent_filtered` adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/adjacent_filtered.html), which passes both the current and the next element in the range to your predicate and is, thanks to the predicate, applicable to a larger range of problems. Boost.Range however also has the [`uniqued` adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/uniqued.html).

Another possibility would be to simply keep a reference to the range, which is easy to do with a lambda in C++11:

```
std::vector<T> v;
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
    [&](T const& x){
      // use v, with std::find for example
    }), v.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there will be easier to use simple traversal algorithm(via for) rather then use std::bind. Of course, with std::bind you can use other functions and predicates(which depends on previous elements). But in your example, you can do it via simple std::unique.