# Erase duplicate element from a vector

Tags: c++, duplicates

I create a vector inside  with several elements in c++ and I want to remove the elements of vector with the same values. Basically, I want to remove the whole index of the vector that is found a duplicate element. My vector is called person. I am trying to do something like:

```
for(int i=0; i < person.size(); i++){
    if(i>0 && person.at(i) == person.at(0:i-1)) { // matlab operator
        continue;
    }
    writeToFile( perason.at(i) );   
}
```

How is it possible to create the operator 0:i-1 to check all possible combinations  of indexes?

Edit: I am trying GarMan solution but I got issues in for each:

```
        set<string> myset;
        vector<string> outputvector;

        for (string element:person)
        {
            if (myset.find(element) != myset.end())
            {
                myset.insert(element);
                outputvector.emplace_back(element);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you sort the vector?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove elements from a c++ vector where the removal condition is dependent on other elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412434/remove-elements-from-a-c-vector-where-the-removal-condition-is-dependent-on-ot)

Comment: No, its actually necessary to remain still.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200486/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-unsorted-stdvector-while-keeping-the-original-or

Comment: Why don't you just use a set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an "in-place" version (no second vector required) that should work with older compilers:

```
std::set<std::string> seen_so_far;
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = person.begin(); it != person.end();)
{
    bool was_inserted = seen_so_far.insert(*it).second;
    if (was_inserted)
    {
        ++it;
    }
    else
    {
        swap(*it, person.back());
        person.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you. Note that the order of elements is not guaranteed to stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you can `sort` your `vector`, you can simply call `std::unique`.

```
#include <algorithm>    

std::sort(person.begin(), person.end());
person.erase(std::unique(person.begin(), person.end()), person.end());
```

If you cannot `sort`, you can use a `hash-table` instead by scanning the vector and update the hash-table accordingly. On the same time, you can easily check if one element is already existent or not in `O(1)` (and `O(n)` in total). You don't need to check all other elements for each one, which will be time-costly `O(n^2)`.

Comment: It seems OP cannot sort the vector, so another approach is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work

```
unordered_set<same_type_as_vector> myset;
vector<same_type_as_vector> outputvector;
for (auto&& element: myvector)
{
    if (myset.find(element) != myset.end())
    {
        myset.insert(element);
        outputvector.emplace_back(element); 
    }
}
myvector.swap(outputvector);
```

Code written into reply box, so might need tweaking.

Comment: Unexpected token : in for (auto&& element: myvector) statement.

Comment: Like I said, the code might require tweaking. Are you using a moderm compiler? Did you rename the myvector to your vector?